# Searching a Record from Middle of the Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine-orm

I am facing issue in finding the data from MySql table.

**Table A:**

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| ID    | Table_b_fk  |Value | age | name              | score |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| 01    | 01          | 255  |  21 | Tom               |  65   | 
| 02    | 02          | 36   |  20 | Peter             |  95   | 
| 03    | 03          | 25   |  22 | John              |  65   | 
| 04    | 04          | 36   |  20 | Bond              |  95   |<<----First 
| 05    | 05          | 258  |  22 | Smith             |  65   | 
| 06    | 06          | 420  |  20 | Robert            |  95   | 
| 07    | 07          | 258  |  22 | Nisarg Patel      |  65   | 
| 08    | 08          | 16   |  21 | Peter             |  95   | 
| 09    | 09          | 25   |  23 | J0k               |  65   | 
| 10    | 10          | 36   |  22 | Prodigitalson     |  95   | 
| 11    | 11          | 205  |  22 | Silver            |  65   |<<----Next
| 12    | 12          | 37   |  20 | Json              |  95   | 
| 13    | 13          | 285  |  23 | Villa             |  65   | 
| 14    | 14          | 36   |  22 | Parker            |  95   | 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

**Table B:**

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| ID    | Result      | M1   |  M2 | name              | score |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| 01    | Pass        | 30   |  26 | Tom               |  65   | 
| 02    | Pass        | 30   |  20 | Peter             |  95   | 
| 03    | Pass        | 25   |  60 | John              |  65   | 
| 04    | Pass        | 100  | 100 | Bond              |  95   |<<----First 
| 05    | Pass        | 55   |  65 | Smith             |  65   | 
| 06    | Pass        | 80   |  95 | Robert            |  95   | 
| 07    | Pass        | 65   |  75 | Nisarg Patel      |  65   | 
| 08    | Pass        | 56   |  71 | Peter             |  95   | 
| 09    | Pass        | 90   |  96 | J0k               |  65   | 
| 10    | Pass        | 96   |  96 | Prodigitalson     |  95   | 
| 11    | Pass        | 100  | 100 | Silver            |  65   |<<----Next
| 12    | Pass        | 47   |  92 | Json              |  95   | 
| 13    | Pass        | 82   |  73 | Villa             |  65   | 
| 14    | Pass        | 86   |  72 | Parker            |  95   | 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

I am joining TableA & TableB, where in TableA `Table_b_fk` is foreign key to TableB.

I am finding the record which matches the TableB column `M1 & M2 = 100`.

**My Scenario: 1**

I know the first occurrence of the match record ID : `04` in `TableA`. I want to do a search to find the next record with `M1 & M2 = 100`. (Record Id-11) But the search should not start from **01**. It should start from the last found record Id. That is from **O4** the search should start to find the next occurrence of the record.

My Try:
I tried to find using Limit but it didn't help me to find. Can some one help me in this?

**Edit: 1**

**My Scenario: 2**
In my second case my TableB has repeated Data and the ID was foreign in TableA. How can I fins the record. ? with the matching ID/M1/M2 values: I found a solution for that. I just want to find the Current Record FOREIGN KEY and Check for the next occurrence of the record in the same table and I can get the next record rite?

In this case my TableB record are not as same as TableA records. In other words my TableA records will point to tableA. Many-to-one. Is this rite?

**Edit: 2**

Thanks for all your efforts and knowledge I found a solution for scenario:2 check it:

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (
  ID Int,
  Result VARCHAR(20),
  M1 INT,
  M2 INT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  Score INT);

INSERT INTO TableB VALUES
( 11    , 'Pass'        , 30   ,  26 , 'Tom'               ,  65   ), 
( 13    , 'Pass'        , 30   ,  20 , 'Peter'             ,  95   ),
( 80    , 'Pass'        , 25   ,  60 , 'John'              ,  65   ),
( 81    , 'Pass'        , 100  , 100 , 'Bond'              ,  95   ),
( 90    , 'Pass'        , 55   ,  65 , 'Smith'             ,  65   ),
( 96    , 'Pass'        , 80   ,  95 , 'Robert'            ,  95   ),
( 97    , 'Pass'        , 65   ,  75 , 'Nisarg Patel'      ,  65   ),
( 98    , 'Pass'        , 56   ,  71 , 'Peter'             ,  95   ),
( 99    , 'Pass'        , 90   ,  96 , 'J0k'               ,  65   ),
( 100    , 'Pass'        , 96   ,  96 , 'Prodigitalson'     ,  95   ),
( 101    , 'Pass'        , 10  , 10 , 'Silver'            ,  65   ),
( 103    , 'Pass'        , 47   ,  92 , 'Json'              ,  95   ),
( 201    , 'Pass'        , 82   ,  73 , 'Villa'             ,  65   ), 
( 222    , 'Pass'        , 86   ,  72 , 'Parker'            ,  95   )
;


CREATE TABLE TableA
    (`ID` int, `Table_b_fk` int, `Value` int, `age` int, `name` varchar(13), `score` int)
;

INSERT INTO TableA
    (`ID`, `Table_b_fk`, `Value`, `age`, `name`, `score`)
VALUES
    (01, 11, 255, 21, 'Tom', 65),
    (02, 81, 36, 20, 'Peter', 95),
    (03, 80, 25, 22, 'John', 65),
    (04, 97, 36, 20, 'Bond', 95),
    (05, 81, 258, 22, 'Smith', 65),
    (06, 06, 420, 20, 'Robert', 95),
    (07, 81, 258, 22, 'Nisarg Patel', 65),
    (08, 08, 16, 21, 'Peter', 95),
    (09, 96, 25, 23, 'J0k', 65),
    (10, 101, 36, 22, 'Prodigitalson', 95),
    (11, 222, 205, 22, 'Silver', 65),
    (12, 12, 37, 20, 'Json', 95),
    (13, 201, 285, 23, 'Villa', 65),
    (14, 101, 36, 22, 'Parker', 95)
;
```

Solution for that is:

```
SELECT a.id  
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a 
ON a.Table_b_fk = b.id
WHERE M1 = 100 and M2 = 100  AND a.ID>4 limit 1
```

where the limit just limits the next record.. (answer is 5).

I case of `Doctrine 2`: Use the below Query code.

```
$qry = $this->manager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('e', 's'))
        ->from('YOUR_DOMAIN', 'e')
        ->Join('e.table_b_k', 's')
        ->where("s.m1 = ?", $valueone)
        ->andwhere("s.m2 = ?", $valuetwo)
        ->andwhere("e.id > ?", $currentrecord)
        ->setMaxResult(1);
```

Note: `YOUR_DOMAIN` here is the TableA. TableA and TableB should be joined through the Mapping so we dont need to Join/Reference int he Query.. directly as TableB. The will be done by the second line Join in the above example. It is not tested as of now.

Comment: Can you use SQL fiddle to show what you have done ?

Comment: @Vivek its a big DB i just given a sample its hard to develop the DB in fiddle.. :(

Comment: In what sense is one record 'first' and the other 'second'? Is it because the id of the 'first' record is lower than the id of the 'second' record?

Comment: nope in my order I selected the first set of record from the table as with m1 and m2 as 100. so the next record will be next..

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Do you want both '04' and '11' in the result set, or only the '11' record?

Comment: only 11.. and i found a solution.. with below answers.. that helped me..

Comment: (that should have been stated in the question, not in the answer) Why only '11' and not only '04' ? If there were three matching records, would you want one or two of them in the result set? Which one(s) ?

Comment: @wildplasser i have mentioned that in my question as Next record... with an arrow pointing.. i think you didnt saw my question well.. also  i am not looking for 3 match records as you see i just want the next match record so limit will do that for me.. no matter how many records match, i just need the next match record.

Comment: You mean: `I am finding the record which matches the TableB column M1 & M2 = 100.` ? That is the only indication in the whole question of what you intend to do. The rest are your scenarios to actually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this give it a try

```
SELECT b.id AS next_id FROM tableb b LEFT JOIN tablea a 
ON (b.id =a.Table_b_fk ) WHERE b.M1=100 AND b.M2 =100 AND b.id >4 
ORDER BY b.id ASC  LIMIT 1
```

It gives the next occurrence of **M1 =100 and M2 =100 **

**See [Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cbcd/1)**  it returns `11` the next occurrence **M1 =100 and M2 =100 **

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )

Comment: kindly check my My Scenario: 2

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. it worked..more over your fiddle example is very helpful @dianuj

Comment: Your answer is perfect for my Scenario : 1 so i would like to accept your answer.. thanks once again for your help.. hope you like my scenarios.. and i found the solutions..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are looking for this:

```
SET @id:=4;

SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Table_b_fk =
    (SELECT MIN(ID)
     FROM TableB
     WHERE (M1,M2) = (SELECT M1, M2 FROM TableB WHERE ID=@id)
           AND ID>@id)
```

This query will select the second row from TableA that has M1=100 and M2=100 in the second table.

Comment: Nope! the query finds the first record and then with that id ti selects the second row.. in my case I know the Id of the first record found with that I want to search the second record.!

Comment: @TomPHP then there are more rows with the same ID in your TableB. If they have the same ID but also the same M1 and M2 you could try with `WHERE (M1,M2) = (SELECT DISTINCT M1, M2 FROM TableB WHERE ID=@id)` but if there are more values, how can you know wich one to select?

Comment: @TomPHP if you launch this query SELECT DISTINCT M1,M" FROM TableB WHERE ID=4 you get 100,100 but also other records? How do you know wich one to choose?

Comment: I think I have to check the entire DB now some of the records are duplicated... its hard to find those.... because I am working with million of records... let me try with DISTINCT

Comment: @TomPHP have a look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2063f9/1 it only has tableb but it returns correctly ID=11...

Comment: Your table is wonderful but I want to get the Id matched with TableA that is the ID of tableA wher the TableB rcord was matched.

Comment: Kindly check my kindly check My Scenario: 2

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. but it didnt helped me to find the ID in first tableA as you worked on with my tableB alone.. but your answer is the base for my solution.. Thank you so much @fthiella

Comment: @TomPHP fiddle is for tableB alone but once you have the ID you can find records in tableA, my answer has the full query

Comment: As you see i want to run the query again for that..but when i join two table together i can get the id of the TableA in single Query.. thats what I  meant...!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT a.id  
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a 
ON a.Table_b_fk = b.id
WHERE M1 = 100 and M2 = 100  AND b.ID>4
```

output:

```
 ID
 11
```

[demo FIDLLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a097/4)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. it worked..more over your fiddle example is very helpful @echo_Me

Answer (score 1):

> I am finding the record which matches the TableB column M1 & M2 = 100.

Assuming you mean:

> I am finding the **tableA** record which matches the TableB column M1 = 100 AND M2 = 100.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM table_b b
   WHERE b.id = a.tableb_fk
   AND b.m1 = 100 AND b.m2 = 100
   );
```

UPDATE: since the OP appears to want to suppress *the first* matching record from the result (I assume: *the one with the lowest id*), one could add an extra EXIST to the WHERE clause to suppress the *first* match:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM table_b b
   WHERE b.id = a.tableb_fk
   AND b.m1 = 100 AND b.m2 = 100
   AND EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM table_b bb
       WHERE bb.id < b.id
       AND bb.m1 = 100 AND bb.m2 = 100
       )
   );
```